# Spring Boot - updated from 1.2.3.Release to 1.5.0.RELEASE

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I updated following:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

and afterwards I started maven with:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

and I got this trace in the console, which mentions a non parsable POM:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM 
C:\Users\05906\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-
dependencies\1.5.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.0.RELEASE.pom: in 
epilog non whitespace content is not allowed but got r (position: END_TAG 
seen ...</build>\n</project>r... @2606:12)  @ 
C:\Users\05906\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-
dependencies\1.5.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.0.RELEASE.pom, line 
2606, column 12
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.smartinnotec.legalprojectmanagement:smartinnotec-
legalprojectmanagement-main:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT 
(C:\Users\05906\Documents\workspace-sts-
survey\maven.1498452192342\smartinnotec-legalprojectmanagement-main\pom.xml) 
has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM 
C:\Users\05906\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-
dependencies\1.5.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.0.RELEASE.pom: in 
epilog non whitespace content is not allowed but got r (position: END_TAG 
seen ...</build>\n</project>r... @2606:12)  @ 
C:\Users\05906\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-
dependencies\1.5.0.RELEASE\spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.0.RELEASE.pom, line 
2606, column 12 -> [Help 2]
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, the content in

```
C:\Users\05906\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.5.0.RELEASE
```

seems ok.

Comment: Try running mvn with `-U` to force Maven to redownload the dependencies. Perhaps the downloaded POM got corrupted somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but nothing changed  - same fault

Comment: Delete the local cache in the directory org.springframwork and rebuild. The download seemed to be corrupted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check end of your pom.xml file (spring-boot-dependencies-1.5.0.RELEASE.pom) on line 2606. It should only contain a `</project>`, but seems to have something starting with an 'r' after it.

If it is corrupted, you can easily fix it, by just removing it from the .m2 folder and letting Maven redownload it on the next build.

Other ways this issue could occur is if you have an old Maven version, and there is some construct in the pom.xml it does not yet now, but this is not the case for you.